# webpage "root" doesn't display right

Tags: html, url, web, display

My problem is this. When I go to the sites url, it looks broken,
but if I click the home button on the page, it reloads to a correct render.
The site is using openCart.

This is the url: http://haetta.se/

This is the working page url: http://haetta.se/index.php?route=common/home

Comment: Most likely your styles do not get loaded probably, depending on the base path of your request. You can easily debug that yourself using your web browsers development console. Take a look at the "Network" tab in there. Failing requests should show up.

Comment: On the first page the body has a class of "page-home" and on the second example it has "page-common-home". Don't know why these are different, but that seems to be why it isn't working!

Comment: OK, congratulations, looks like you did a decent debugging job so far! However we certainly cannot say anything about _why_ that is the case without your code... You will have to take a look the view template and maybe the index action in the controller.

Comment: Well, it had to do with how the template was constructed, so I guess it generates slightly different tags depending if it is the landing page (first page) or the "home-page" that you access via the navigation. Thanks for support anyhow :)